# Using a tab bar where each tab can have different views associated with it

Tags: ios

I have an array which contains 2 types of items (lets call them type a and type b) which are to be displayed in a table view.

The table view can be filtered such that either just items of type a are displayed, or just items of type b, or all items are displayed and the user can control which filtering is applied by hitting one of 3 corresponding tabs.

So this suggests that my app's root controller should be a tab bar controller.

If that were the only requirement then I would make the tab bar controller have 3 table view controllers, however there is another requirement that I don't know how to design it in a clean way:

If there are no items to be displayed for any of the filters then instead of an empty table view there should be displayed an image and some text (the image and text is different depending upon which filter is selected). So maybe this could have been achieved by setting background images for the table view BUT if filter a is applied then in addition to the images/text a button should also be displayed - which I am assuming cannot be set as the background to a table view. Hence implying that I need a set of separate view controllers to handle displaying the image/text/button views.

I suppose I could have the tab bar controller dynamically swap in and out these view controllers with the table view controllers depending upon if there are items to display for each filter or not, but this seems messy.

So then I was thinking maybe the tab bar controller should own 3 navigation controllers, and each navigation controller has as its root view controller a controller to display the image/text/button if there are no items, otherwise it would push a table view controller onto its stack (and pop it off if the number of items goes down to 0).

Is this a valid option? Is there a canonical pattern for my described behaviour?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually fairly easy. Use a `UITabBarController` as your main interface. The view controller for each tab will be a subclass of `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`. Each table view controller will load the data appropriate for the its tab. If each tab behaves the same (other than the filter) then this works great as your logic will be in one controller implementation. If you need different behavior per tab, no big deal, customize as needed.

Comment: Thank you, I see you edited it to change from a UITableViewController to a UIViewController, so presumably you think that is a better approach than using a UITableView? Could I use a UITableViewController and create a UIView as a container view, then place other subviews (ImageView, UIButton, table view) within that? Are the disadvantages/advantages of this versus creating a subclass of UIViewController?

Comment: Your question is exactly why I changed it. If you don't want the `tableView` to be the container view for the controller I would start with a `UIViewController`. Other than that, the main reason to start with a `UITableViewController` is because it's pre-configured with a `tableView` with `dataSource/delegate` set. Otherwise, no advantage. I usually use `UIViewController` and add my own `tableView` as it's easier to customize.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't read to me like you want to go with a `UITabBarController`. Consider placing a `UISegmentedControl` with 3 segments on the top of the main `UIView` and placing a `UITableView` below it.

Then you can do

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(selectionChanged:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and implement the desired changes to the `tableView` dataSource and/or background image in the method

```
-(void)selectionChanged:(id)sender;
```

This approach allows you to place all of the logic within one `UIViewController`.

Comment: Thanks - if the product marketing department wants it to look like a tab bar, is it possible/easy to customize a segmented control to mimic a tab bar's appearance?

Comment: @Mungbeans No, and it's not a good idea. If you must use a tab bar, then you will need 3 different view controllers. However, you can still write on subclass of `UITableViewController` and create 3 instances instead of writing 3 separate subclasses. This will cut down on redundancy a fair bit.